# How to deodex galaxy s5 lollipop

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom, stock-rom, rom-manager

First, I pull **app fodder**, **priv-app folder** and **framework folder** from system folder in my phone using adb command:

adb pull /system/app app/

adb pull /system/priv-app/ priv-app/

adb pull /system/framework framework/

And then i create a folder name system to contains the three folders i pulled from my phone(app fodder, priv-app folder and framework folder). After that i used LBD 2.5 by JoelDroid to deodex it. After deodex successful i tried to push it back into my system folder. So i copy it into my SDcard and use root explorer to move it into system folder. But the problem is that, it always fail. I have granted root permission already but it still fail to move. So i try to use other app like ES Explorer. But it still fail. It show the message that there was not enough memory. So i delete priv-app folder in system and copy from my sd card back. But it still fail.

I got some questions here.

1. If i can push it back to my system folder, does it mean my phone deodex?
2. Does it mean i deodex my rom, if i can push it back?
3. How can i push it back? Please help.! I wanted to install xposed and also want to learn about it too. Thank everyone. :)